# /bin/sh -c docker : not found returned a non-zero code: 127

Tags: docker, containers, dynatrace

The command `/bin/sh -c docker login  xxxx.live.dynatrace.com -u XXXX -p XXXXX` returned a non-zero code: 127

I am also facing this error when i am trying to execute my default docker file.

The code is here as follows:

```
    FROM node:10
    WORKDIR /usr/src
    RUN apt-get -y update
    RUN docker login  xxxx.live.dynatrace.com -u XXXX -p XXXXXX
    COPY --from=sqx97905.live.dynatrace.com/linux/oneagent-codemodules:all / /
    ENV LD_PRELOAD /opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/lib64/liboneagentproc.so
    COPY . .
    RUN npm install
    EXPOSE 8080
    CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

i need to login so that i can copy the dynatrace agent so i had put the login command ahead of the COPY command. It works fine when i am logged into the terminal but i need to log into the dynatrace at run time then i am facing `/bin/sh : 1 docker not found`

Comment: You misunderstood how COPY works. The --from flag is used to copy files from a previous stage. So it will not work for your workflow.
Also docker is not installed you the node.js base image, you would have to manually install it in order to use it. It is not clear what you are trying to achieve here. Maybe explain what you try to achieve step by step.

Comment: You can’t run `Docker` commands inside a Dockerfile at all.  In what you show there doesn’t really seem to be a need for it in any case.